# node-ipc cluster only using 1 worker

Tags: javascript, node.js, cluster-computing, ipc

I am using node-ipc alongside cluster in nodejs on windows 8.1, and have successfully clustered an ipc server and created as many processes as I have CPU's (4 in my case), all of them sharing the same port and id.

I am connecting multiple clients to this clustered server and am expecting the master process to delegate the task to a worker that is free. However this does not work and the master always chooses the same worker.

I have checked and all the worker processes are running. How can I get it so that the master chooses the least busy worker every time?

Below is the server code

```
var os = require('os');
var numCPUs = os.cpus().length;
var cluster = require('cluster');
var ipc = require('node-ipc');

if (cluster.isMaster) {

    console.log("I am master, launching workers");

    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
        console.log("worker " + i + " launched");
    }

} else {

    ipc.config.id = 'worldserver';
    ipc.config.retry= 1500;
    ipc.config.silent = true;

    console.log(`I am worker #${cluster.worker.id}`, process.pid);

    ipc.serve(
        function(){
            ipc.server.on('sayhello', function(data,socket) {
                    console.log(`I am worker #${cluster.worker.id}`, process.pid);
                    ipc.server.emit(
                        socket,
                        'message',
                        'hello'
                    );
                }
            );
            ipc.server.on('error', function(e) {
                console.log('IPC ERROR!!', e);
            });
    });

    ipc.server.start();
}
```

here is the client code

```
var ipc=require('node-ipc');

ipc.config.id   = 'hello';
ipc.config.retry= 1500;
ipc.config.silent = true;

setInterval(function() {
    ipc.connectTo(
        'worldserver',
        function(){

                console.log("sending something");
                ipc.of.worldserver.emit(
                    'sayhello',
                    "true"
                );

                ipc.of.worldserver.on(
                    'message',
                    function(data){
                        console.log('I got this message from the server:');
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                );  

        }
    );
}, 20);
```